# Resize a div according to the window scrolling and the div min height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve this:

When users scroll page, i need a header that will be fixed, but before to stick it, this div should shrink to a certain height, and after that this div become fixed.

[This is my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/Zg8CV/)

As you can see, there are some strange behavior on shrinking, i think that my approach is not so right.

```
header.css("height", "-=" + (Math.abs(start - scrollTop)));
spacer.css("height", "-=" + (Math.abs(start - scrollTop)));
```

So, what is the best way to do it?

**UPDATE**:

Now i'm at this point, but i need to make it more smooth

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zg8CV/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var headerElement = //Select header element here,
        scrollTopToLookoutFor = //Put value you want to check for here,

    if($("body").scrollTop() > scrollTopToLookoutFor || $("html").scrollTop() > scrollTopToLookoutFor){
                headerElement.addClass("fix-header");
    }
            else{
                headerElement.removeClass("fix-header");  
            }

});
```

Have a css class here with required styles

```
.fix-header{
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I know how to fix element, making it sticky or whatelse, the point is: when WINDOW.offset.top == HEADER.offset.top, reduce HEADER height gradually until HEADER have a height of 50px, then make HEADER fixed

Comment: ?, i dont' have fixed nothing for now

Comment: Oh right, I get it now but when you say make it more smooth, could you explain further?